# Regex hyplen and slash

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex :

```
"/^(?:.+)-([0-9]+)$/"
```

and i have this text :

> tutu-toto-6

Because i need to capture the number '6'.

But i have one problem, when my text is

> ti-ti-6/tata-6

or

> titi/tata-7

my regex work and capture the last number, What Should I do to not capture the last number when my text : ti-ti-6/tata-6 or titi/tata-7

Comment: So you only want to match the last number if the text is: `tutu-toto-6`(Exactly this text) ? If yes why don't you write 6?

Comment: You have to tell us what the logic is *supposed* to be. Why shouldn't the 6 or 7 be captured in the last two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
"~^[^/]*?-(\d+)~"
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW4aE6/1)